# how can google.com put a tab focus on an element that is not focusable

Tags: javascript, html, web, accessibility

Please go to google.com and search for 'dictionary', navigate through tab key and select "skip to main content":

[step1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MINCU.png)

After hitting enter, the dictionary element gets focused:

[step2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7DfCm.png)

When I inspect it, it's a div with a `aria-level` attribute with no `tabindex`.

[step3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nA0d3.png)

So my question is how can a non-focusable element gets focused like that?

EDIT: When I tried to save that exact div element into a global var and call `focus`, it never gets focused.

Comment: Hi @T.J.Crowder, edited my question. When I tried to call `.focus` on that div element in devtools, it never gets focused.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you press <kbd>Enter</kbd> on that message, JavaScript code adds `tabindex="-1"` to the element and focuses it. Before <kbd>Enter</kbd>:

[image: Google page with Elements panel showing no tabindex on the main content div]

After:

[image: Google page with Elements panel showing tabindex="-1" on the main content div]

When focus leaves the element (presumably a `blur` event handler), JavaScript code removes the `tabindex` from the element.

You can see this if you right-click the element and reveal it in the Elements panel, then watch the element as you tab until you see that element again. For instance, if you click anywhere near the top of the body of the page after opening the Elements panel and <kbd>Shift+Tab</kbd>, eventually you get that same "Show main content" box again, and when you press <kbd>Enter</kbd> you can see the `tabindex` get added (and then see it get removed when you move away).

Comment: You're my hero. Saved my day. I couldn't upvote due to my low reputation.

Comment: I wonder why they bother adding and removing the attribute. `tabindex="-1"` is intended for programmatic (non keyboard) focusing.

Comment: @brennanyoung - The whole thing seems a bit over-engineered. :-)